# brew install dnvm failed

Tags: asp.net, macos, homebrew, dnvm

When I try to install asp.net via these commands below:

```
brew tap aspnet/dnx
brew update
brew install dnvm
```

But after running the last command I got error:

```
==> Installing dnvm from aspnet/dnx
==> Cloning https://github.com/aspnet/Home.git
Cloning into '/Users/user/Library/Caches/Homebrew/dnvm--git'...
remote: Counting objects: 9, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
remote: Total 9 (delta 0), reused 4 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (9/9), done.
==> Checking out branch dev
Error: No such file or directory - dnvm.sh
```

My Homebrew Version:

```
Homebrew 1.1.12
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 4b25; last commit 2017-04-05)
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula relies on the presence of `dnvm.sh` at the root of the git repo but that file doesn’t seem to exist anymore. Unfortunately the authors of this tap won’t fix this because [the repo deprecated](https://github.com/aspnet/homebrew-dnx). You should use the Mac installer from [get.asp.net](https://get.asp.net) as written in [their README](https://github.com/aspnet/homebrew-dnx/blob/master/README.md).